# How to prevent duplication when randomising numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
from random import randint
def random_number():
    return randint (1,10)

rn1 = random_number()

rn2 = random_number()
while rn2 == rn1:

    rn2 = random_number()

rn3 = random_number()
while rn3 == rn1 or rn3 == rn2:

    rn3 = random_number() 

rn4 = random_number()
while rn4 == rn1 or rn4 == rn2 or rn4 == rn3: 

    rn4 = random_number()

rn5 = random_number()
while rn5 == rn1 or rn5 == rn2 or rn5 == rn3 or rn5 == rn4: 

    rn5 = random_number()
```

I've struggled with this small piece of code for a while now. I'm trying to get the program to randomly generate 5 numbers. The problem was that the program could generate the same number twice. I'm trying to make sure that there is no duplicate numbers within the 5 generated with an algorithm. However, the code still prints duplicates. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, they want 5 numbers below 10, not 1 to 5 in a random order.

Comment: Worth noting you can cleanly do this with `random.sample`, something like `random.sample(range(1, 10), 5)`.

Comment: You could shuffle the numbers 1 to 10 and then deal 5 off the top.

Comment: Shuffle an array of unique items and then pop out your samples one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

def random_numbers():
    return randint(1,10)

def main():
    my_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        value = random_numbers()
        if value in my_list:
            continue
        else:
            my_list.append(value)
    print(my_list)

main()
```

Comment: any reason for down voting?

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random

numbers = random.sample(range(1, 11), 5)
```

This does *sampling without replacement*, which seems to be what you want.

Note that `random.sample(pop, k)` selects a sample of size `k` from a population `pop` (list or otherwise), and the bounds of `range(a, b)` are `a <= x < b`, while the bounds of `randint` are `a <= x <= b` - so you need to add 1 to the end of your `range` call.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use built-in numpy functionality:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(10,5)
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Note that `choice` has a `replacement` keyword as well to switch between sampling with and without replacement, like so:

```
np.random.choice(10, 5, replace=False)
```

Note that all of these rely on `np.arange` to build the array to sample from, so that you'd sample from `[0,1,...,9]` - if you want to sample from 1-10 you can do:

```
np.random.choice(range(1,11), 5, replace=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add each random number to a list and then check in that list to see if it has already been made:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 5:
    n = random_number()
    if n not in numbers:
        numbers += [n]
```

Note that while this method is simple to understand it is not very efficient when you are wanting a large subset of the original set of numbers, for example trying to get 1000000 numbers from the set of numbers 1 to 1000000 would take a long time due to trying numbers already added to the list.